# Spring AOP: exclude avoid final classes and enums from pointcut

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using try to implement Logging using Spring AOP. I have defined the

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mycom..*(..))")
private void framework() {}

@Around("framework()")
public Object aroundAdviceFramework(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("DEBUG:: {}  {}  Enter", jp.getTarget().getClass().getName(), jp.getSignature().getName());
    Object returnVal = jp.proceed(jp.getArgs());
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("DEBUG:: {}  {}  Out", jp.getTarget().getClass().getName(), jp.getSignature().getName());
    logger.info("INFO:: " + jp.getTarget().getClass().getName() + " " + jp.getSignature().getName() + " Finished:");
    return returnVal;
}
```

There are lot of classes under mycom package and its subpackages. Some of the classes are enum and final class. 
Because of this I am getting

```
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.mycom.util.BancsServiceProvider]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.mycom.util.BancsServiceProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
```

Is there a way to exclude all the final classes and enum classes from logging using some kind of regular expression.
Note:I have enum classes all over in different packages. It would be difficult to exclude them using complete class names.

---

**Update 2014-11-17 (trying kriegaex's solution):**

I tried using

```java
@Pointcut("!within(is(FinalType))")
```

but I am getting following error

```
Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 10
```

!within(is(FinalType))

I have added this maven dependency in the pom file

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have also added this maven dependency

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now, everything is working like charm. Any ideas, whats happening here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently you can exclude enums, aspects, interfaces, inner types, anonymous types via `is()` pointcut syntax which was introduced in AspectJ 1.6.9, see also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25543865/1082681).

What you cannot do at the moment is exclude final types via AspectJ syntax. But I think it would make sense, so I created a [ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449739) for it.

How to exclude enums:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mycom..*(..)) && !within(is(EnumType))")
```

---

**Update:** [AspectJ 1.8.4](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/aspectj/aspectj-1.8.4.jar) has been released, see also overview in the official [download section](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php). On Maven Central the download is not available yet, but it will be soon, I guess. When available, [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.4) will be valid, currently it yields a 404 error.

So why is this release interesting? Because the ticket mentioned above has been resolved and there is a new pointcut primitive `is(FinalType)` available as of now, see [1.8.4 release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-184.html).

So now the full solution you requested looks like this:

```java
@Pointcut(
    "execution(* com.mycom..*(..)) && " +
    "!within(is(EnumType)) && " +
    "!within(is(FinalType))"
)
```

I verified that it works like this.

Comment: The ticket has been resolved and AspectJ 1.8.4 released, see updated answer.

Comment: I tried now I am getting error Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 10
!within(is(FinalType))

Comment: Then you are not using version 1.8.4 for compilation.

Comment: now !within(is(FinalType)) is working fine. Please read the edited question.

Comment: I do not understand what else you want to know. You are using a brandnew feature from AspectJ 1.8.4, but did not have that version in your build and runtime dependencies. Does that really need explanation? Now it is working, be happy. P.S.: If you do not edit your question in a way which makes visible what is original question and which part is the update, it is hard to recognise.