# Spring AOP: How to exclude all final methods from Aspectj

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I cannot find how to **exclude** all **final** methods in **aspectj 1.9.1**.
I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676584/spring-aop-exclude-avoid-final-classes-and-enums-from-pointcut) for earlier version but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only for final classes, not methods, you can check here - https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/org.aspectj.matcher/src/org/aspectj/weaver/patterns/TypeCategoryTypePattern.java

What you can do is to move your final methods to final class and exclude it by smth like that

```
@Before("!within(is(FinalType)) && execution(* your_method_name(..)) ")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't solve my problem but at least I know that final methods cannot be excluded in such manner.

Comment: this solved my problem too but intellij shows `!within(is(FinalType))` as an error, isn't it valid?