# AspectJ within(is(FinalType)) missed

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using aspectJ 1.8.10.
In my code I have a bean with ScheduledExecutorService:

```
@Bean
public ScheduledExecutorService backgroundTaskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
}
```

When bean instantiated, proxy class throws:

```
.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService
```

I know, that ScheduledExecutorService haven't constructor, is the root cause. But I need to configure my aspect's pointcut to exclude FinalType classes.
Like this:

```
@Before("!within(is(FinalType)) && execution(* your_method_name(..)) ")
```

But, as I mentioned, aspectJ version 1.8.10 is not recognize is(..) syntax. (Intellij IDEA warning Cannot resolve symbol 'is').
Application starts without AOP issues, but fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Is there any changes is aspectj > 1.8.4? (is(..) syntax)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676584/spring-aop-exclude-avoid-final-classes-and-enums-from-pointcut  - 1.8.4 version has that feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Spring AOP configured to force creation of CGLIB proxies even for interface types like `ScheduledExecutorService`, probably via

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Just remove the `proxyTargetClass = true` part or set to `false`, then your aspect will work. You do not need any `is(FinalType)` pointcut designator, just write something like

```java
@Before("execution(* schedule*(..))")
```

in order to intercept scheduler methods.

---

**Update:** Let me explain why `is(FinalType)` does not help you and why thinking it does not work is wrong:

Read the error messages again:

```
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class
  [class java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService]:
  Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class;
  nested exception is
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService
```

"No visible constructors" does not mean the class is final, it means what it says: There just are no visible constructors. Actually the inner static class `Executors.DelegatedScheduledExecutorService` is package-protected in `java.util.concurrent` where `Executors` resides. If you look at the source code you see:

```java
static class DelegatedScheduledExecutorService
        extends DelegatedExecutorService
        implements ScheduledExecutorService {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService e;

    DelegatedScheduledExecutorService(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        super(executor);
        e = executor;
    }

    // (...)
}
```

See? No `final` class here. The actual problem is that CGLIB just cannot create a subclass due to JVM limitations: You cannot subclass something that is in another package if it is not `public`.

This is why I told you to let Spring use a JDK dynamic proxy and take advantage of the fact that in this case subclassing is not necessary but implementing an interface is enough.

Comment: Seems to be true, but it isn't work. Also, when I remove that part of annotation(in two config classes), it fault with Proxy class "Bean named '..serviceBean' is expected to be of type '..serviceBean' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy207'". And what about is(FinalType) clause? Why version 1.8.10 isn't support it, but 1.8.4 does?

Comment: I tried with both 1.8.9 and 1.8.10, `is(FinalType)` works nicely. I have no idea why you think it does not work. And BTW, you are not using AspectJ but Spring AOP. The latter just uses the syntax of the former but only supports a subset of features. Anyway, the pointcut works in both AOP frameworks. As for your error message, there must be another problem. Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (ideally on GitHub) I cannot say anything intelligent about it because I neither see your configuration nor your Maven build nor your application and aspect classes.

Comment: I have updated my answer, explaining in more detail why your approach is not working.

Comment: Magic - after "gradlew clean build" there are no issues with proxy classes. With (proxyTargetClass = true). Very strange, but thank you very much)